# Linux two way password encryption?

Tags: linux, ssh, password-encryption

I am looking for a way to encrypt the password for my perl script.

The password is stored in an XML file called config.xml

I have tried before to come up with a way to encrypt the password using various perl modules.

But I keep running into the same problem, decrypting the password.

The problem is either once the password is encrypted I can never get to it again, like it works with `crypt`. Or the other problem being I have to include in the other script the function to decrypt the password. Therefore making the encrpytion pointless in the first place.

So I got to thinking, what if I use a Linux application instead of a perl module.

So my question pretty much boils down to this,

**Is there any application I can install for Debian/Ubuntu that will give me two password encryption that I can use in my perl script?**

I must have a way to decrypt the password as it is needed for the SSH connection to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ssh-keys](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) instead of a password.

Comment: The thought has occurred to me but the server I am connecting to is a VMware ESXi box. I think the keys on the ESXi box would get wiped out every time the box reboots. I know that happens if I leave a script on the root file system of the box. I would love to use keys it would be so much easier.

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer to my problem. I have to insert the files into a special tarball on the server so they persist through reboot. YOU WIN!

Comment: Thanks for that info that was helpful. The only thing I am trying to understand is whether all ssh keys are created equal. ESXi uses dropbear, will OpenSSH keys for on dropbear?